# App Indexing "Open in App" doesn't work

Tags: android, indexing, deep-linking, android-app-indexing

So, I was trying to implement app indexing to allow "Open in App" feature from google search (in Chrome app).

I've implemented the following sections from google docs https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/:

1. Add Deep Linking to your App

   ```
   <activity
       android:name=".DeepLinkActivity">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
           <data
               android:scheme="http"
               android:host="dl.mysite.com"
               android:pathPattern="/" /> <!-- Home page -->
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```
2. Connect your App

   I've verified and approved the website from Webmaster and Play console.
3. Provide Deep Links

   ```
   <link rel="alternate" href="android-app://com.MyApp.MyApp/http/dl.mysite.com/" />
   ```

I've tried testing my link "android-app://com.MyApp.MyApp/http/dl.mysite.com/" in https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/test and the link opens my app home page.
However, the listing corresponding to my site in google search results (in Chrome app) has no "Open in App" function.

I'd like to have this "Open in App" function. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you getting any errors for app indexing in Webmaster Tools?

Comment: I had the build in beta. I just moved it to production in play console and it worked!

Comment: What do u mean with "I had the build in beta"?

I have currently the same problem and i can't find a solution.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948746/app-indexing-android-link-in-head-doesnt-work

Maybe u can help?

Comment: The build was set up for **BETA TESTING** in **Google Play Developer Console**. App Indexing worked once I moved the apk to **PRODUCTION**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to a similar question addresses this problem.

[App Indexing Android - "<link>" in "<head>" doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948746/app-indexing-android-link-in-head-doesnt-work/32964711#32964711)

To quote, "It'll work only from google search results page. If your website is properly indexed and appears in google search results, check if exists in the website's page source in google's cached content: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:yourwebsite.com.

Also, you might need to move your apk to PRODUCTION if it's in BETA TESTING in Google Play Developer Console."

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution

```
<activity ... android:launchMode="singleTask">
[...]
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="@string/domain"
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:pathPattern=".*" />
                <data
                    android:host="@string/domain"
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:pathPattern=".*" />
</intent-filter>
```

[Different behaviors in Open in App from browsers and other applications to my webView app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62038818/different-behaviors-in-open-in-app-from-browsers-and-other-applications-to-my-we/62058466#62058466)

Answer (score 1):

`android-app://...` is a normal deep link and is different from App Indexing.

[App Indexing include `http://...` and `https://...` urls only!](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations)

If you want App Indexing to work,
What you need is a `/.well-known/assetlinks.json` as on website.

It's called Google/ Firebase App Indexing - https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing

There is an **App Links Assistant** built into Android Studio that will help you generate the `assetlinks.json` file and test URLs among other useful things.