# Different behaviors in Open in App from browsers and other applications to my webView app

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Different behaviors detected:

WhatsApp app, ask for "open in app", but, when app selected leaves my app behind and just go to default page (or keep existing page if aplication is already open)

Chrome browser detects link from example.com/place and goes to example.com/place as expected.

Firefox browser don't ask for "open in app" on example.com link, uses Firefox browser.

Instagram app don't ask for "open in app" on example.com link, uses Instagram webview browser.

Any ideas how to fix this? Does Whats App modify link ?

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="@string/domain"
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:pathPattern=".*" />
                <data
                    android:host="@string/domain"
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:pathPattern=".*" />
</intent-filter>
```

When I try to debug this situation, Chrome launches my app and debugger stops on "loadUrl" method on breakpoint as expected.
WhatsApp don't stop on breakpoint like if just open other app without any url associated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting

```
<activity ... android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Solve the whatsapp isue.